# Hovering will add space between blocks

Tags: html, css

in the menu there's always some strange appearing space appearing, when hovering above them. Since I'm new with this i have no idea from where this comes from

```css
nav,
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px solid black;
  display: inline;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  padding: 4px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}
nav li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
}
nav a:hover {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline;
  background-color: #cc0000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#currentlink {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline;
  background-color: #cc0000;
  padding: 4px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <a href="home.html">Home</a>
    <a id="currentlink" href="news.html">News</a>
    <a href="bilder.html">Bilder</a>
    <a href="videos.html">Videos</a>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: You are adding padding when hovering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nav a:hover` has a padding and border set but they're not on `nav a`. This is basically adding these to the width of the element.

Move:

```
padding: 4px; 
border: 1px solid black;
```

to `nav a` and this will be fixed.

You also have merged the padding and border in the `nav li` styles

Comment: Hm, but now there are spaces between the menu point. How can i delete those now?